# Adding more distros to my laptop

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, versions

This question sounds noob to me but I am confused after being away from computing for some time (maybe I have had serious concussions or a brain tumor).

I bought a laptop some while ago and thought it was cool to let the salesmen dual boot it with some Ubuntu LTS. Now I am stuck with Ubuntu 17.10 and I do not have a clue how to fix this. Some features I need (e.g. RStudio) are problematic on this Ubuntu version and I just like feeling comfort with a LTS.

I think the easiest way is to just add 16.04 to a new partition but I can not even find out how to add partitions in linux and nothing comes up when writing grub in the dashboard.

I have often set up dual-boot with Windows and various distros but for some reason I am stuck now.

Comment: boot from a LiveCD and use gparted. 17.10 uses Wayland by default: Wayland prohibits GUI programs from running as root. So GUI programs that require root privelages are effectively broken on Wayland.

Comment: And you don't need to add another distro (you can but you don't have to). You can boot a USB with 16.04, start the installation and use "something else" to select the same partitions now in use by 17.10. Typically `/` and `swap`. The latter can be selected as is, for the other also tick format, and if UEFI, also select the EFI partition but do not format. If other partitioning schema you may [edit] and post a GParted screenshot so we can suggest the best strategy.

Comment: I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI .